# Windows 2012 server, update error

Tags: windows-server-2012, automatic-updates

At this afternoon I decided to apply an pack of updates in my Windows 2012 server (about 1 GB).

After it downloaded, it starts to apply them and self restarted.

When the windows come up again, a blue screen (I hope not "of the dead") with a message apears (the message was in portuguese):

"Failure at Windows update configuration. Rolling back changes. Do not turn off the computer"

This is already running for more than 2 hours, and I don't have any access to the console.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're sure that the machine is hung, the best answer is probably just wait it out.  I've seen rollbacks like this take a really long time.  Your only other recourse is to do a hard reset, but then you risk just making the entire process start over.  In short, give a few more hours and see what happens.

Comment: After 5 hours, it back to live. And the updates were apply.